# Using python to add and delete documentdb instances

Tags: python, pymongo, aws-documentdb

I have setup a documentdb instance and used the [following instructions](https://documentdb-immersionday.workshop.aws/introduction/querycluster/connectusingpython.html) to connect to it using python. I am able to connect to the instance and do basic operations like inserting data and reading data with no issues.

I am looking in to scaling the cluster by adding more instances which in [this section of the document](https://documentdb-immersionday.workshop.aws/introduction/scalecluster/performscaleoperations.html) advises you to go to the console and do it. I am wondering if it is possible to add and delete instances using python? As i would want to automate things and not go to console such operations. I have looked elsewhere in the official aws docs as well and not found anything.

Answer (score 1):

Yes! You can use the Python SDK for DocumentDB to perform these operations. For more information, refer to - https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/docdb.html